# Scrollintoview confusion

Tags: javascript, scroll

I want to scroll to specific div when I click on a link and I don't know what is happening.

Here is the code on link:

```
onclick="scrolling('.gallery')"
```

I want to send the string gallery to a function.

Here is the function:

```
  function scrolling (x){
          console.log(document.querySelector(x));
          document.querySelector(x).scrollIntoView();
  }
```

The problem is that the view does not scroll down when I click the link.
BUT, the console log works AND I have an animation on the page when the window scrolls there that it goes ACTIVE when I click the link.
It is like it goes instant there and come back again.

Does anyone knows what is happening??

---

Ok I have a normal menu

```
<ul>
   <li><a href="#" onclick="scrolling('.gallery')">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
```

and I am trying to make the page scroll to specific div when I click a link.
the js code that I have now is this

```
function scrolling (x){
  console.log(document.querySelector(x));
  document.querySelector(x).scrollIntoView();
}
```

Comment: can you elaborate on your BUT part? somehow the explanation doesn't make much sense to me, do you have a working example of your problem?

Comment: thank you for your answer!
When the page scrolls down there I have an animation that it gets active (when the view is there) and when I click the link it is happening the animation, but the page does not seem to scroll there. Maybe its happening instantly and gets back again.
Does this make more sense??
I want to stay there when it scrolls.

Comment: You really should provide enough code so that we can reproduce your problem. Otherwise we can't really help you.